# Obtener URL de imagen de un Input file

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Me encuentro con el problema de que al momento de obtener la URL de una imgagen al cargarla en el input file e imprimirlo en consola me da como resultado: fakepath + imagen, ¿cómo puedo obtener la direccion completa?

Anexo código:

```js
function crearFotoDerecho() {
  //0.- Recuperar datos
  let datosImagen = document.getElementById("imgDer").value;
  alert(datosImagen);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imgDer">Imagen Derecho</label>
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-dark" id="imgDer">
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="crearFotoDerecho()">
    Enviar Img Der
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: La imagen no se ha subido al servidor y, por motivos de seguridad, los navegadores nunca te van a mostrar la ruta en el cliente. Edita la pregunta para explicar detalladamente lo que necesitas hacer con la imagen, que no sea obtener la ruta en disco. :-P

Comment: necesito que al dar click al boton, imprima la imagen que subo principalmente, lo del console solo lo uso para ver la ruta @Triby

Answer (score 2):

Los navegadores no permiten que javascript pueda acceder a la pc (con mucha razón).

Si lo que necesitas son los metadatos de la imagen estan en `document.getElementById("imgDer").files[0]`. Tambien es muy común que lo que quieras sea obtener la url para mostrar un preview de la imagen, en ese caso tenes que usar la API [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) de la siguiente manera:

```js
function crearFotoDerecho(){
  //0.- Recuperar datos
  let file = document.getElementById("imgDer").files[0];  

  const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      document.getElementById("imgPreview").src = event.target.result;
  });

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imgDer">Imagen Derecho</label>
        <input type="file" class="btn btn-dark" id="imgDer">
    </div>        

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="crearFotoDerecho()" >Enviar Img Der</button>    
</form>

<img id="imgPreview"/>
```

Comment: Gracias!! me sirvio de mucho

Comment: @miki si esta respuesta te ayudó a resolver el problema, no te olvides de marcarla como aceptada, para que la publicación quede completa. Lee sobre [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para más información. Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y así ganarás una nueva medalla). Saludos.